# Error in PDE: Length of Derivative operator

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages

I am trying to solve Poisson's equation in a cylinder with Dirichlet boundary conditions for the top, bottom, and sides of the cylinder, but I am getting the following error from NDSolve:

> `NDSolve::derlen`: The length of the derivative operator Derivative[0,2] in u^(0,2)[r,z] is not the same as the number of arguments.

Here is the code I wrote for it:

```
Remove["Global`*"]
(* Constants *)
u0 [r, z] = 1;
γ = 0.00001;
L = 0.1;
rad = 0.01;
V0 = 1000;
V0other = 1;

maineqn = 
  Laplacian[u[r, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"] == 
   E^u0[r, z] - 1 - γ;
vol = Cylinder[{{0, 0, -L/2}, {0, 0, L/2}}, rad];
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[vol]
Graphics3D[vol]
bc1 = DirichletCondition[u[r, z] == V0, z >=  L/2  || z <=  - L/2  ]
bc2 = u[rad, z] == V0other;
NDSolve[{maineqn, bc1, bc2}, u, {r, θ, z} ∈ vol]
```

Any suggestions? I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Comment: You've written `u` as a function of `r` and `z` only, but indicate it should be a function of `r, θ, z`, both in the `Laplacian` and in `NDSolve`.